# How to load a new FXML scene into Broder Pane

Tags: java, javafx, anchor, fxml

```
private void loadUI(String ui) {
    BorderPane root = null;
    try {
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(ui + ".fxml"));
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    borderPaneCenter.setCenter(root);
}
```

and ui.fxml file in package but still this is not working

**This is Exception**

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3470)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$8100(Scene.java:3398)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3766)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**ui.fxml file have In anchor pane(having Border Pane) and  in this (Main Scene) scene i want to set in Center of this (of main border pane) border pane**

Comment: The code your are showing swallows any exception, yet you show a stack trace. Please ensure that you have a real [mcve] for us.

Comment: Please create a [mre] demonstrating the problem, then add it to your question via an [edit]. See [ask].

Comment: You did not provide a [mcve], however this looks like one of your event handlers in one of the fxmls takes the wrong type of event as parameter. Be sure to post the part of the fxml that is supposed to register the handler and the method it's supposed to register.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the message `argument type mismatch`. This error message is received when you are trying to load a FXML file into a variable that are of differing types.

Your `root` variable is a `BorderPane` but you say that your FXML file's root is an `AnchorPane`. To fix this error, these types must match.

You could change `root` into a `AnchorPane`, but this relies on the root of your FXML file being `AnchorPane`. If you decide later that you want to, for example, wrap your entire scene in a `ScrollPane`, your code would break again.

A much better solution is to change `root` to a `Parent`. All containers extend `Parent`, and so your code will work no matter what container is at the root:

```
Parent root = null;
try {
    root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(ui + ".fxml"));
}
```

If you need to control your `BorderPane` from code, you can simply give it an `fx:id` in your FXML file, and then, in your controller, create a `BorderPane` variable which has the same name as the id. For example:

***.fxml**

```
...
<BorderPane fx:id="borderPane" ... >
...
```

**Controller.java**

```
@FXML
private BorderPane borderPane;  // name borderPane must match fx:id above
```

Comment: This addresses one issue, but it's not the reason for the stacktrace shown in the question: this would result in a `ClassCastException`; `FXMLLoader.load` does not receive any information about the target type the result is assigned to and because of type erasure the invocation is not different, whether the target type is `Object` or `BorderPane`. The compiler just adds a hidden cast there.